# Split design view / source view windows scroll to wrong location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on an aspx file in Visual Studio.  I have the window split to show both design view and source view of the file.

I thought that when I clicked in either the design half of the window or the source half of the window, the other half would scroll to the location of those same controls in the other half of the window.  Indeed, it does scroll, but it scrolls to almost the most very outside container of the area I'm working on, which makes it go to near the very top of the page or near the very bottom of the page, WAY far away from where I'm working.  I can only view the part I want to see using the mouse scroll wheel, but as soon as I make a change, the other window scrolls away again!

I'd rather it not scroll at all than do this.  Is there a way to sync them, or turn off the auto scroll?

I've searched online over several different days trying to find an answer but I don't see anyone else mentioning this.

Comment: Never mind.  After searching for days, something occurred to me and I tried it and it worked.  Apparently it was because most of the page was enclosed within a panel!  I only have the panel there because the new page I'm making is supposed to copy the behavior of another, existing page.  I've commented out the panel tags for now and the design and source views are now syncing normally.